# Reset bootstrap modal fires before button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I needed to clear the inputs on a bootstrap modal window whenever it is closed. To do this I added a hidden.bs.model handler.

Why does the event handler hidden.bs.modal fire to clear the inputs before the on click event associated with the "Run" button in the same modal? It prevents me from being able to use the values in the inputs as they are already cleared by the hidden.bs.modal

```
// BUTTON LOOKUP
$( '.container').on("click", ".btnGetPerson", function() {
    var dlic = queryPersonInputValue.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}$/);
    console.log('the value of variable dlic is  :' +dlic);        
    // other REST stuff 
});

// RESET LOOKUP MODAL ON CLOSE
$('#queryPersonModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    console.log('modal closed');
    $(this)
        .find("input,textarea,select")
        .val('')
        .end()
        .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
        .prop("checked", "")
        .end();

});
```

`console.log('the value of dlic is :' +dlic);` always prints `null` since adding the `hidden.bs.modal`.

I have added the HTML to a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bigalnz/gLw8pnx3/1/

Comment: How does your html look like? And you could only use the hidden.bs.modal-handler to read the values before clearing the fields, in this way your code gets more simple.

Comment: @Blauharley I decided to use bs.modal.show to clear the fields, but that still doesn't explain why the events fire in that way.

Comment: This hidden.bs.modal listener catches an event before your click listener because of the order these listener were attached to and of how your html is structured. A click listener catches an event before another click-listener when it was attached to some button before the second listener. It also depends on how a button is embedded in your modal, for an event can pass several listener going down to a button and bubbles in the same direction upwards again.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about **event bubbling** and **event propagation**:

When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors, terminating at the `window` object.

You have already used this principle when writing the click handler for `.btnGetPerson` button, using `.container` element.

---

Bootstrap Modal Js implements the click handler for the elements that have the `data-dismiss` attribute in the following way:

```
this.$element.on('click.dismiss.modal', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', $.proxy(this.hide, this))
```

where `this.$element` is the modal element, and `this.hide` is the method that hides the modal and triggers the `hidden.bs.modal` event.

---

So, when a `[data-dismiss="modal"]` is clicked, we have the following event sequence:

```
0: button.btn.btn-primary.btnGetPerson
1: div.modal-footer
2: div.modal-content
3: div.modal-dialog
4: div#queryPersonModal.modal (*)
5: div.container
6: body
7: html
8: document
9: Window
```

So the `click.dismiss.modal` will run only after all the click handlers for `.btnGetPerson`, `.modal-footer`, `.modal-content`, `.modal-dialog` had run.

Accordingly, all the events handlers attached to the `.container` element will run after `#queryPersonModal.modal` events.

---

So, my solution is to attach the click handler directly to `'.btnGetPerson'` element:

```
$(".btnGetPerson").on("click", function() {      
    // ...
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z6ntys7f/23/

Or, if the modal html is inserted into page asynchronously, you can take the following approach: 
- remove the `data-dismiss` attribute from the button
- add `$('#queryPersonModal').modal('hide');` in the click handler:

```
$(".container").on('click', '.btnGetPerson', function(e) {
   // var dlic = queryPersonInputValue.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}$/);
   var dlic = $('#query-name').val();
  console.log('the value of variable dlic is  :' +dlic);        
  // other REST stuff 

  $('#queryPersonModal').modal('hide'); 
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z6ntys7f/25/

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for detailed answer.